# Is there a simple way to write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left[ (n+a)^2 + b^2 \right]^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following sum for $a > 0$ and $b>0$.
$$
S(a,b) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left[ (n+a)^2 + b^2 \right]^2}
$$

Is there an easy way to write the answer? The series definitely converges, and is seemingly related to the following two identities:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2} = \frac{\pi}{2a} \coth(\pi a) - \frac{1}{2a^2} \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left[n^2 + a^2\right]^2} = \frac{\pi}{4a^3} \coth\left(\pi a\right) + \frac{\pi^2}{4a^2}\mathrm{csch}\left( \pi a \right) - \frac{1}{2a^4}
$$

I have considered hitting the first of the above two identities with a derivative in some way, but I can't quite formulate how to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Added constraints on $a$ and $b$

Comment: Do you enjoy polygamma functions ?

Comment: I do not enjoy polygamma functions. I was hoping that the mess of polygammas mathematica spits out can be written nicer, maybe in terms of $\coth$'s and other such functions.

Comment: These formulae may be of help: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+a} = -\psi(a)$ and $\psi(1-x) -\psi(x) = \pi cot(\pi x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}e^{-mx}\,dx= \frac{1}{n^2+m^2},\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}\text{ for }x\in(0,2\pi)$$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\,xe^{-mx} = \frac{2m}{(m^2+n^2)^2} $$
(which follow from integration by parts and standard results for Fourier series) to convert your series into nicer integrals. In terms of the digamma and trigamma functions we have
$$ S(a,b) = \frac{\text{Im } \psi(1+a+ib)}{2b^3}-\frac{\text{Re }\psi'(1+a+ib)}{2b^2}. $$